# Confusion about batch_size in n<<p dataset with batch_size > n in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm a bit confused about code which runs perfectly fine but I don't understand why.

I'm in a n < < p scenario with 2 fold more features than examples. I've accidentally set batch size to a value > n.

What is the default behavior of keras then? Just falling back to pure gradient descent where weights are averaged at the end of an epoch?

I'm using this setup in a supervised binary classifier setting as well as in a LSTM/Autoencoder based unsupervised anomaly detector

This adds an additional confusion, since I was thinking that in the LSTM - case n % batch_size should be zero.

Answer (score 0):

I've digged a bit into the source code and I think I have the answer to those questions.

1. Is Keras "degenerating" to ordinary gradient descent if batch_size > n?

The answer is yes. As can bee seen in the method [batch_shuffle](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2.2.0/keras/engine/training_utils.py) starting in line 334 (note: I'm linking to V2.2 to preserve line numbering) if batch_size > n the whole batch is returned. Here the relevant code and output:

```
import numpy as np
index_array = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5])
batch_size = 72
batch_count = int(len(index_array) / batch_size)
#batch_count = 0

last_batch = index_array[batch_count * batch_size:]
# last_batch = array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

index_array = index_array[:batch_count * batch_size]
#index_array = array([], dtype=int64)

index_array = index_array.reshape((batch_count, batch_size))
#index_array =array([], shape=(0, 72), dtype=int64)

np.random.shuffle(index_array)
index_array = index_array.flatten()
return np.append(index_array, last_batch)
# np.append(index_array, last_batch) = array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

2. Why is the LSTM working even if n % batch_size <> 0?

The requirement that n % batch_size = 0 holds only for stateful LSTMs, again found evidence in the following [code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2.2.0/keras/engine/training.py), line 817 which raises an error ONLY if stateful==True and n % batch_size <> 0